# "standortübergreifend" or "Standort-übergreifend" or "den Standort übergreifend"

Tags: compound

Is there any clear rule defining the right way to combine the noun "Standort" with the suffix "-übergreifend"?

I found https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/getrennt-und-zusammenschreibung but it is not explicitly defining my case, as far as I can judge it.

Comment: I think you get an idea if you look at the examples under [-übergreifend](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_uebergreifend)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for the dash separation, this is a common compound construction.
The singular article is just wrong, since more than one site is affected. (One could consider it as an uncounted amount.)

This leaves the first choice of your title: standortübergreifend.